# printing a children's full tree recursively in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, process

sry for not being familiar with question conventions since im new here.

i want to write a script that prints the full children's tree recursively of a given pid.

i got so far as:

```
ps h -ef | awk '$3='$input_pid' {print $2}' | sort -n
```

but this is just for printing the immediate children of the given pid (sorted).

the question is: how can i summon the recursive function for every child-pid of the given pid?

thanks...

Comment: Does `pstree` do what you want ?

Comment: `ps axf` might be your friend.

Comment: `pstree $input_pid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
pstree -p parent_process_ID
```

If you want only pid to be displayed

```
pgrep -P parent_process_ID
```

or the simpler and a detailed display.

```
ps auxfww | grep -v grep | grep process_name
```

Comment: the command "pgrep -P parent_process_ID" works only when i use it out of the script. for example, when i run it on the pid 2 it prints me all the processes running from 1 to 32656. why is that?

Comment: Because pid 2 belongs to kthreadd process, which is kernel threads and you will see lots of children for kthreadd process. try this command too **ps -f -p 2 --ppid 2** for kthreadd process and its children.  And  pgrep works in the script too, I am not sure why it is not working with your script. try giving complete path of pgrep ie **/usr/bin/pgrep**, it should work.

Comment: i made a mistake. the command "pgrep -P parent_process_ID" works perfect. thanx!!!